# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor

Tags: java, interceptor

When I run my tomcat, I get the `ClassNotFoundException` in my browser.

```
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean 'loginInterceptor' of type [com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor] for bean with name 'loginInterceptor' defined in URL [file:/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/86vision/target/haitian/WEB-INF/classes/springMVC.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor

...
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor] for bean with name 'loginInterceptor' defined in URL [file:/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/86vision/target/haitian/WEB-INF/classes/springMVC.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor

...
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor
```

But, however, my `LoginInterceptor.java` is in existence.

[image]

---

I have tried clean-> install in maven life circle.
Restart tomcat.

But there is no result.

---

**EDIT**

My configutration of `LoginInterceptor` in `springMVC.xml` is this:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.ldl.vision86.business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"></bean>

            <!-- 国际化操作拦截器 如果采用基于（请求/Session/Cookie）则必需配置 -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: are you using maven? Is it a spring boot application or simple spring mvc application?

Comment: @SanketD, I use Maven.

Comment: can you paste your application context config file here?

Comment: @SanketD, do you mean `web.xml` or what?

Comment: Are you using the annotation to configure the spring beans?

Comment: @SanketD, I update my post, have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141817/discussion-between-sanket-d-and-qg-java).